# How to make the scroll vertical left bar scrolling to the top?

Tags: jquery

I have a big list of gender products so the right scroll bar appears, when i click on a gender product a model displays and shows the list of the products of this gender inside this model and in the same time a left scroll bar in the left appears.
I made a j query code inside this model let me when i click on the button scroll up to scroll on the top of my model, but the problem that when i click on my button the right bar scrolls not the left bar, so how can i make the left bar scrolling to the top not the right?
- this is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function()
{
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100)
{
    $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
}
else
{
    $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
}
});

$('.scrollup').click(function()
{
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 
600);
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: could you please add some html as well, or best create a code snippet to make clear what you are asking, thanks

Comment: Hi - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below my answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" *(by clicking the checkmark beside the answer)* to close out the question. ***Also note that you can upvote instead of*** **(or in addition to)** ***the checkmark, to reward answers that were also helpful.***

Comment: Hi Nassim - following up again. Could we trouble you to select a best answer -- or provide you own and select that -- to close out the question? That would help us out. *Many Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);`, make it:

```
$("#Id-of-your-modal-container-div").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
```

Here's an example:

[<kbd>jsfiddle Demo</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/knpfzc85/)

```js
$('#btnScrollMain').click(function(){
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 },600);
});

$('.btnMdlTop').click(function(){
 $("#modalDIV").animate({ scrollTop: 0 },600);
});

$('#btnShowModal').click(function(){
 $("#modalDIV").fadeIn();
});
```

```css
#modalDIV{position:absolute;top:5%;left:5%;width:60vw;height:60vh;}

#modalDIV{background:#888;color:lightblue;overflow:auto;display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<button id="btnShowModal">Show Modal</button>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<button id="btnScrollMain">Top</button>

<div id="modalDIV">
    <p>SCROLL WAAAAY DOWN... Use one of the buttons to schlep back to top...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <button class="btnMdlTop">Top</button>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <p>Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered weak and weary, over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten code...</p>
    <button class="btnMdlTop">Top</button>
</div>
```